# How to create a popup in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need a help , I am new to jQuery and java script .

My TG.js like

```
var initializeTemplateGrid = function () {
var templateGrid = $("#templateGrid");
templateGrid.kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                if (type == "read") {
                    return {
                        limit: data.pageSize,
                        offset: data.page-1,
                        sort: data.sort[0].field + ":" + data.sort[0].dir
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "Records",
            total: "TotalRecordCount" 
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        pageSize: 25,
        serverSorting: true,
        sort: { field: "TemplateName", dir: "asc" }
    },

    
    sortable: {
        allowUnsort: false
    },
    pageable: true,
    pageable: {
        pageSizes: [10, 25, 50]
    },
    noRecords: {
        template: "No Templates Available"
    },
    columns: [
        {
            field: "TemplateName",
            title: "Template Name"
        },
        {
            template: "<div >#if(data.SiteCount > 0){#<a Id='tt' href=''>#:SiteCount# Sites</a>#} else{#N/A#}#</div>",
            field: "SiteCount",
            title: "Name TEMP"
        }
    ]
});
```

};

Currently for TemplateName if sitecount >0 then by href ='' I am moving to main page.
Now I  want to create a popup when I click that link with data.SiteCount value.

How can I do it ??

I was tried below

```
    $(function () {
    $("#dialog1").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $("#opener").click(function () {
        $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
    });
});
```

but I am getting a error dialog key word not supported with my project .

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention what other library you have referenced in your project. Add the followings in the layout page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then white a reusable function like this in the layout or your js file:

```
function showDialogUI(msg, closedTrigger) {
    $('#dialogModal span#dialogModalMessage').text(msg);
    $("#dialogModal").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            if ((closedTrigger === null) || (closedTrigger === undefined)) {                
            }
            else {
                closedTrigger();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then from any page call the function like this:

```
showDialogUI('There is a test message.', null);
```

In the place of `null` you can pass a function reference which will be called when the Dialogue box is closed.